# Neural Network probabilities converging to biases

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation, java, softmax

I'm creating an Android app which can use a variety of classification formula, and while I have normal Softmax done correctly, I keep having an issue with the Softmax Neural Network. After about 10 iterations, all of the dot values on the forward pass become negatives, so their values are stored as 0, causing the resulting layers of h1, h2, and scores to become 0+bias. This means that every result is the same, regardless of input. I feel like somewhere there is a typo in my code, but I've repeatedly compared and contrasted it with my partner's code (which is written for iOS) and can't find any differences. Hopefully someone here can tell me where I've gone wrong.

public List gradient(List weights, double[] X, int Y, int D, int K, double L, int nh){
        int length = D*nh + nh + nh*nh + nh + nh*K + K;
        List grad = new ArrayList(length);

```
    List<Double> W01 = new ArrayList<Double>(D*nh);
    List<Double> b1 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    List<Double> W12 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh*nh);
    List<Double> b2 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    List<Double> W23 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh*K);
    List<Double> b3 = new ArrayList<Double>(K);

    //Parse Parameters
    int count = 0;
    int end = count + D*nh;
    while(count < end){
        W01.add(weights.get(count));
        count++;
    }
    end = count + nh;
    while(count < end){
        b1.add(weights.get(count));
        count++;
    }
    end = count + nh*nh;
    while(count < end){
        W12.add(weights.get(count));
        count++;
    }
    end = count + nh;
    while(count < end){
        b2.add(weights.get(count));
        count++;
    }
    end = count + nh*K;
    while(count < end){
        W23.add(weights.get(count));
        count++;
    }
    end = count + K;
    while(count < end){
        b3.add(weights.get(count));
        count++;
    }

    //Forward Pass

    double dot;
    double sum;
    List<Double> h1 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        dot = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < D; j++){
            dot += X[j]*W01.get(i + j*(nh));
        }
        sum = dot + b1.get(i);
        if(sum > 0) {
            h1.add(sum);
        }
        else{
            h1.add(0.0);
        }
    }

    List<Double> h2 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        dot = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < nh; j++){
            dot += h1.get(j)*W12.get(i + j*(nh));
        }
        sum = dot + b2.get(i);
        if(sum > 0) {
            h2.add(sum);
        }
        else{
            h2.add(0.0);
        }
    }

    List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<Double>(K);
    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
        dot = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < nh; j++){
            dot += h2.get(j)*W23.get(i + j*(K));
        }
        sum = dot + b3.get(i);
        scores.add(sum);
    }


    //scoreMax used to prevent overflow
    double scoreMax = 0;
    double score;
    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
        score = scores.get(i);
        if(score > scoreMax){
            scoreMax = score;
        }
    }

    //denom = Σ(i:k) exp(Θ_i · X)
    double denom = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
        denom += Math.exp(scores.get(i) - scoreMax);
    }


    List<Double> probs = new ArrayList<Double>(K);

    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        //prob_i = exp(Θ_i · X)/denom
        probs.add(Math.exp(scores.get(i) - scoreMax) / denom);
    }

    //Backward Pass

    List<Double> dProbs = new ArrayList<Double>(K);

    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
        if(i == Y){
            dProbs.add(probs.get(i) - 1);
        }
        else{
            dProbs.add(probs.get(i));
        }
    }

    List<Double> dW01 = new ArrayList<Double>(D*nh);
    List<Double> db1 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    List<Double> dh1 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    List<Double> dW12 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh*nh);
    List<Double> db2 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    List<Double> dh2 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh);
    List<Double> dW23 = new ArrayList<Double>(nh*K);
    List<Double> db3 = new ArrayList<Double>(K);

    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < K; j++){
            dW23.add(dProbs.get(j)*h2.get(i) + L*W23.get(j*nh + i));
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
        db3.add(dProbs.get(i));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        dot = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < K; j++){
            dot += dProbs.get(j) * W23.get(j + i*K);
        }
        if(h2.get(i) > 0){
            dh2.add(dot);
        }
        else{
            dh2.add(0.0);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < nh; j++){
            dW12.add(dh2.get(j)*h1.get(i) + L*W12.get(j*nh + i));
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        db2.add(dh2.get(i));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        dot = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < nh; j++){
            dot += dh2.get(j) * W12.get(j + i*(nh));
        }
        if(h1.get(i) > 0){
            dh1.add(dot);
        }
        else{
            dh1.add(0.0);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < D; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < nh; j++){
            dW01.add(dh1.get(j)*X[i] + L*W01.get(j*D + i));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nh; i++){
        db1.add(dh1.get(i));
    }

    grad.addAll(dW01);
    grad.addAll(db1);
    grad.addAll(dW12);
    grad.addAll(db2);
    grad.addAll(dW23);
    grad.addAll(db3);


    return grad;
}
```